# Cannot convert type value of type Observable<Store> to expected argument type Observable<Store?>

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm getting an error which says the following:
`Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<Store>' to expected argument type 'Observable<Store?>`

So the method I'm calling `StoreMock(state: stateSubject, store: storeSubject)` seems to expect an optional for the observable storeSubject. But I'm not sure why it should matter if I pass in a non-optional. Shouldn't it be fine as it will always be there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the object into an Optional:
`StoreMock(state: stateSubject, store: storeSubject.map(Optional.some))`

Just one call will fix this.

Comment: Would this be in the call to the mock so: StoreMock(state: stateSubject, store: storeSubject.map(Optional.some)). It seems I still get an error

Comment: Yes. Answer updated.

Comment: Hm I tried that: StoreMock(state: stateSubject, store:storeSubject.map(Optional.some)), but it still seems to get the observable error

Comment: The exact same error? That's not likely. For a better response, I will have to see the definition of this `StoreMock(state:store:)` method.

Comment: Not sure what changed but after compiling a few times seems it worked for me!